# Copy SVG to clipboard as image

Tags: javascript, image, svg, clipboard, copy-paste

I am working on an application where I want to provide a copy button for svg to be copied as an image to clipboard which can be pasted at other places.

I tried using clipboard API but it has a lot of security restrictions, moreover it does not seem to work on http and works with png only.

I also tried the `document.execCommand('copy')` by creating a div with the image but it worked for me only in MS Word but not in slack or stack overflow (not sure why).

I want to replicate the behaviour of chrome/firefox's right click context-menu's Copy Image option via Javascript.

Is there some way this is possible? I am open to all ideas. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to have some code to tinker. Depending on your needs, you may try drawing the `svg` inside a `canvas` with javascript like in this example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-draw-an-SVG-file-on-an-HTML5-canvas

Comment: I explored an option for writing canvas, but how to copy that as an image to clipboard?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the sentence about the right click. For your problem, I see no way around the clipboard API.  The `execCommand` strategy does not export a picture, but html code. That is why it works on Word, but not on image processors. You may find useful examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write , but with caveats. I am afraid it is a headache and not portable.

Comment: Thanks @vqf. Any idea how chrome/firefox does it? I doubt they are probably using some APIs other than those provided in JS. Any insights or links would be great.

Comment: What kind of image do you expect it to copy/paste? An SVG image? Then the markup you have is the svg image. A raster image? If so rasterized in which dimensions and why? In which state? (remember that svg images can be animated either through SMIL or CSS, and even interactive)

Answer (score 0):

Just some pointers, not an actual answer. I set up a local example using the info in the comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:2px solid green;" width="300" height="300"> 
</canvas>
      <script>
        function copyCanvas() {
          let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
            let data = [new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })];

            navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(function () {
              alert('Copied');
            }, function (err) {
              alert('Not copied');
            })
          });
        }
  
         let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
         let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         var data = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300"
         height="200">' +
            '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
               '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:50px">' +
                  'Simply Easy ' +
                  '<span style="color:blue;">' +
                  'Learning</span>' +
               '</div>' +
            '</foreignObject>' +
         '</svg>`;
         var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
         var img1 = new Image();
         var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
         var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
         img1.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img1, 25, 70);
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
         }
         img1.src = url;
         setTimeout(copyCanvas, 3000);
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work, but it might be a start. If `copyCanvas()` is called directly, without the `setTimeout`, I get a black picture with the right size in Chrome. I think this means that the canvas is still not drawn. With the delay, the canvas shows the picture, but I get an error saying that it cannot be converted with `toBlob` as it is tainted. This is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image). You might avoid this taint if you can set the CORS policy in your server. I am still not sure about the portability of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the **Base64 code** after the ',' character to end (`PHN2ZyB4bWxu...4=`) and convert it to SVG using any services (like [base64.guru](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image/svg)) then copy the result to your clipboard as an image.

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer, this worked for me.

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svgElement.outerHTML);

await navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({
    'image/png': new Promise((resolve) => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context?.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
            if (blob) {
                resolve(blob);
            }
            canvas.remove();
        }, 'image/png');
    })
})]);
```